# Make the parameters of a query optional?

Tags: node.js, sql-server, tedious

I am using msSqlConnecter with tedious. I have a query which filters based on the parameters provided by the front end. I would like to have the parameters optional and allow the users to not provide them or provide just one of the two. Is there a way to put an if statement based on the existence of field2?

I'm getting the following error:

> RequestError: Validation failed for parameter 'field2'. Invalid number.

Code:

```
var thequery1 = `SELECT country
                        ,sales 
                        ,[Units Sold] as sold
                        ,thedate
                 FROM financial
                 WHERE 1 = 1
                   AND country = @field1
                   AND [Units Sold] > @field2`;

Promise.all([queryTablewithPararams(thequery1, req.body.field1, req.body.field2)])
        .then(
            data => res.json(data)
        );

function queryTablewithPararams(thequery1, field1, field2) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        var con = new msSqlConnecter.msSqlConnecter(config);
        con.connect().then(function() {
            new con.Request(thequery1)
                .addParam("field1", TYPES.VarChar, field1)
                .addParam("field2", TYPES.Int, field2)
                .onComplate(function(count, datas) {
                    resolve(datas);
                }).onError(function(err) {
                    console.log(err);
                }).Run();
        }).catch(function(ex) {
            console.log(ex);
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: You can go ahead with a dynamic sql and append the `and [Units Sold] > @field2` if the @field2 is not null

Answer (score 0):

Just validate `field2` before sending as perameter

> `if (isNaN(field2) || field2 == null) { field2 = 0; }`

```
   function queryTablewithPararams(thequery1, field1, field2) {
        if (isNaN(field2) || field2 == null) { field2 = 0; }
        return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
            var con = new msSqlConnecter.msSqlConnecter(config);
            con.connect().then(function() {
                new con.Request(thequery1)
                    .addParam("field1", TYPES.VarChar, field1)
                    .addParam("field2", TYPES.Int, field2)
                    .onComplate(function(count, datas) {
                        resolve(datas);
                    }).onError(function(err) {
                        console.log(err);
                    }).Run();
            }).catch(function(ex) {
                console.log(ex);
            });
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Taking the suggestion from the OP comment from Joby seems to solve it.

```
var thequery1 = `SELECT country
                        ,sales 
                        ,[Units Sold] as sold
                        ,thedate
                     FROM financial
                     where 1 = 1
                     and country = @field1
                     and [Units Sold] > @field2`
if(req.body.field1){
    thequery1 = thequery1 + 'and country = @field1'
}
if(req.body.field2 > 0 ){
    thequery1 = thequery1 + 'and [Units Sold] > @field2'
}
```